# Why is hardware acceleration not working on my View?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, hardware-acceleration, facebook-messenger

I'm using [Facebook's Rebound library](http://facebook.github.io/rebound/) to replicate the bouncy animations seen in their chat heads implementation. The problem is, most of the time the animation stutters. A few pictures will explain this better. Here's the buttery-smooth chat heads animation:

[image: Facebook Messenger]

And here's my attempt (notice how the animation for the white `View` skips nearly all frames):

[image: Stuttering animation]

Once in a while it works smoothly:

[image: Smooth animation]

Below is the code I'm using currently (the entire project is [up on Github](https://github.com/vickychijwani/BubbleNote/tree/eb708e3910a7279c5490f614a7150009b59bad0b) if you want to set it up quickly). I'm guessing this has something to do with hardware acceleration not being enabled correctly on my `View`. There are 2 `Spring`s in my `SpringSystem`, one for the "bubble" (the Android icon) and another for the content (the white `View` that is displayed on tapping the bubble). Any help on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
        ...
    </application>
```

`AppService.java`:

```
    // the following code is in AppService#onCreate()
    // AppService extends android.app.Service
    // full code at https://github.com/vickychijwani/BubbleNote

    mContent.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

    final Spring bubbleSpring = system.createSpring();
    bubbleSpring.setCurrentValue(1.0);
    bubbleSpring.addListener(new SpringListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSpringUpdate(Spring spring) {
            float value = (float) spring.getCurrentValue();
            params.x = (int) (mPos[0] * value);
            params.y = (int) (mPos[1] * value);
            mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mBubble, params);
            // fire the second animation when this one is about to end
            if (spring.isOvershooting() && contentSpring.isAtRest()) {
                contentSpring.setEndValue(1.0);
            }
        }

        // ...
    });

    final Spring contentSpring = system.createSpring();
    contentSpring.setCurrentValue(0.0);
    contentSpring.addListener(new SpringListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSpringUpdate(Spring spring) {
            // always prints false?!
            Log.d(TAG, "hardware acc = " + mContent.isHardwareAccelerated());
            float value = (float) spring.getCurrentValue();
            // clamping is required to prevent flicker
            float clampedValue = Math.min(Math.max(value, 0.0f), 1.0f);
            mContent.setScaleX(value);
            mContent.setScaleY(value);
            mContent.setAlpha(clampedValue);
        }

        // ...
    });
```

Comment: first of all remove Log.d from onSpringUpdate as it slows down the animation

Comment: @pskink I'm aware of that. I only put that log in afterwards to check if hardware acceleration for the View was correctly enabled.

Comment: instead you could add Log.d to see if the second animation is fired really once

Comment: @pskink yes, the animation is fired correctly every time. I checked it with the logs _and_ the debugger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've figured it out by going through the framework source code.

**TL;DR**: add `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED` to the layout flags when you manually attach a `View` to a `Window` / `WindowManager`; setting `android:hardwareAccelerated=true` in the manifest won't work.

---

I'm [manually attaching my `View` to the `WindowManager`](https://github.com/vickychijwani/BubbleNote/blob/eb708e3910a7279c5490f614a7150009b59bad0b/app/src/main/java/io/github/vickychijwani/bubblenote/BubbleNoteService.java#L54) (because I need to create my UI in a `Service` to emulate chat heads) like so:

```java
    // code at https://github.com/vickychijwani/BubbleNote/blob/eb708e3910a7279c5490f614a7150009b59bad0b/app/src/main/java/io/github/vickychijwani/bubblenote/BubbleNoteService.java#L54
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mBubble = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.bubble, null, false);
    // ...
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    // ...
    mWindowManager.addView(mBubble, params);
```

Let's go digging...

#### Welcome to the Android framework

I started debugging at [`View#draw(...)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/View.java?av=f#14069), then went up the call stack to [`ViewRootImpl#draw(boolean)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java?av=f#2280). Here I came across this piece of code:

```java
    if (!dirty.isEmpty() || mIsAnimating) {
        if (attachInfo.mHardwareRenderer != null && attachInfo.mHardwareRenderer.isEnabled()) {
            // Draw with hardware renderer.
            mIsAnimating = false;
            mHardwareYOffset = yoff;
            mResizeAlpha = resizeAlpha;

            mCurrentDirty.set(dirty);
            dirty.setEmpty();

            attachInfo.mHardwareRenderer.draw(mView, attachInfo, this,
                    animating ? null : mCurrentDirty);
        } else {
            // If we get here with a disabled & requested hardware renderer, something went
            // wrong (an invalidate posted right before we destroyed the hardware surface
            // for instance) so we should just bail out. Locking the surface with software
            // rendering at this point would lock it forever and prevent hardware renderer
            // from doing its job when it comes back.
            // Before we request a new frame we must however attempt to reinitiliaze the
            // hardware renderer if it's in requested state. This would happen after an
            // eglTerminate() for instance.
            if (attachInfo.mHardwareRenderer != null &&
                    !attachInfo.mHardwareRenderer.isEnabled() &&
                    attachInfo.mHardwareRenderer.isRequested()) {

                try {
                    attachInfo.mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded(mWidth, mHeight,
                            mHolder.getSurface());
                } catch (OutOfResourcesException e) {
                    handleOutOfResourcesException(e);
                    return;
                }

                mFullRedrawNeeded = true;
                scheduleTraversals();
                return;
            }

            if (!drawSoftware(surface, attachInfo, yoff, scalingRequired, dirty)) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

In my case [`ViewRootImpl#drawSoftware()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java?av=f#2420) was being called, which uses the software renderer. Hmm... that means the `HardwareRenderer` is `null`. So I went searching for the point of construction of the `HardwareRenderer`, which is in [`ViewRootImpl#enableHardwareAcceleration(WindowManager.LayoutParams)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java?av=f#681):

```java
    // Try to enable hardware acceleration if requested
    final boolean hardwareAccelerated =
            (attrs.flags & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED) != 0;
    if (hardwareAccelerated) {
        // ...
        mAttachInfo.mHardwareRenderer = HardwareRenderer.createGlRenderer(2, translucent);
        // ...
    }
```

Aha! There's our culprit!

#### Back to the problem at hand

In this case Android does not automatically set `FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED` for this `Window`, even though I've set `android:hardwareAccerelated=true` in the manifest. So the fix is simply:

```java
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mBubble = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.bubble, null, false);
    // ...
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            // NOTE
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    // ...
    mWindowManager.addView(mBubble, params);
```

Although the animation is still not as smooth as Facebook's. I wonder why... (before anyone asks: no, there are no copious logs during the animation; and yes, I've tried with a release build)

Comment: I don't add FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED  flag to WindowManager.LayoutParams but when I check Layout.isHardwareAccelerated() it still returns true?

Comment: Do you have `android:hardwareAccelerated=true` in your manifest? That automatically enables hardware acceleration throughout the app I think.

Comment: Of course I have. That means we don't need to add FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED  as you mentioned.

Comment: Well either you're not attaching the View to your Window manually, or you're using a different version of Android that doesn't require you to add `FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED` explicitly. I can't say without seeing the relevant code.

Comment: Exactly the same problem I'm currently having but I'm not sure if I notice anything different.