# not able click on list view in fragments

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-fragments

**OnClickListner is not working!**

I have two text view in each row of my list view which is in **Fragmnet**. I want to pass the ID of the particular row onClick which is not working.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
    newsListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_list);
    newsListView.setClickable(true);
    newsList = new ArrayList<>();
    newsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            System.out.println(position);

        }
    });
    loadNewsList();
    getActivity().setTitle("News");
    newsListView.setClickable(true);
    return view;
}
```

i get this in console on click

```
D/ViewRootImpl@19f3c4b[MusicActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 530252349440}
D/ViewRootImpl@19f3c4b[MusicActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] newFrame=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={isValid=true 530252349440} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
D/ViewRootImpl@19f3c4b[MusicActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@19f3c4b[MusicActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713219/why-is-hardware-acceleration-not-working-on-my-view

Comment: Thanks for your response...i am not able to find solution here! can u help me out in any other way? @sasikumar

Comment: did you debug it?

Comment: Yes i did. i get these lines on click of my list view ,
D/ViewRootImpl@19f3c4b[MusicActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@19f3c4b[MusicActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22705760/listview-setonitemclicklistener-not-working-in-custom-list-view

Comment: now i added    android:clickable="true",android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false" ,i still have the same problem.

Comment: try adding ` newsListView.setClickable(true);` before setting the click listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with XML files . Please share those .